# Sequelize - variable "sequelize" in model definition

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm following Sequelize documentary. In the bottom of [Model Definition](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html) section, I wonder what sequelize variable for ? And could I remove it ?

```
{
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'foo'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here sequelize is just instance of your sequelize connection.

init method of sequelize require two objects as arguments as you can see.

```
Foo.init(

{
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT,  //first argument 
  deadline: Sequelize.DATE
},
 { sequelize, modelName: 'foo' } //second argument

)
```

First argument is all of your model fields and Second argument need sequlize instance and name of your model.

And hence you can't remove it.